# Prove the fractional field $Q(\mathbb{R})$ of the integral domain $\Bbb R$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Prove the fractional field $Q(\mathbb{R})$ of the integral domain $\Bbb R$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

I proved Prove the fractional field $Q(\mathbb{Z})$ of the integral domain $\Bbb Z$ is $\mathbb{Q}$. Using an isomorphism between equivalence classes. Can I do it similarly for this?

Comment: This is true for every field. Given a domain, you construct the field of quotient by "adding" all the inverses of the non-zero elements. But being in a field, all the non-zero elements are already invertible, so you are adding nothing extra.

Comment: The fraction field of an integral domain $R$ is the _smallest_ field containing $R$ (in an appropriate sense). But if $R$ is already a field . . .

Comment: What is $\mathbf{R}$ for you here ? Meaning by that : how is it constructed ?

Comment: Do you have available any results about the uniqueness of universality of fraction fields?

Answer (score 1):

Prove that the ring-homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb R \to Q(\Bbb R)$ given by:

$\phi(x) = [x/1]$ is surjective (it's automatically injective since it's a non-zero map and $\Bbb R$ is a field).

(Hint: this amounts to showing $xy^{-1} \in \Bbb R^{\ast}$, for $x,y\in \Bbb R^{\ast}$).